# UIToolbar not showing on Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I have added **toolbar** on my project for navigating on the web but for some reason it is not showing when I launch app.

### Here is the problem:

- Toolbar showing on Main.storyboard
- [It is **not** showing when I run the app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A67UD.png)
- Also my toolbar was perfectly working before I updated to Xcode 9. I don't know what is wrong right now.

### Things I've tried

- In the inspector I made sure it is not hidden.
- In `viewDidLoad` I've added this line of code: `self.view.addSubview(toolbar)`
- I have also checked other stack overflow questions about this problem but unfortunately couldn't find any solution..

[Here is the GitHub link of the View Controller if it helps](https://github.com/celikomer/remax-store/blob/master/remax-store/Controller/IlanlarVC.swift)

[Screenshot of the storyboard](http://ibb.co/bWo65b)

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: in the screenshot you provided there is a toolbar.. Also, a list of constraints and the storyboard file/screenshot would help too

Comment: Yeah sorry about it. Here is what I'am trying to achive: https://ibb.co/gj5VFb
And list of constraints: http://ibb.co/hXjMow

Comment: I can see the whole xcode, but you haven't expanded the constraints :D.. please fix it, and I would recommend you to add the screenshots to the question (use edit), not to the comments

Comment: @MilanNosáľ unfortunately I cannot add more images to post itself because I don't have enough reputation :/  Here is the expanded constraints: http://ibb.co/bWo65b

Comment: try to add a constraint to set the height of the toolbar (e.g., to 50 points, just to test out if that's the problem)

Comment: I tried adding height constraint of 44 but unfortunately it did not work either:  http://ibb.co/hOFnBG
http://ibb.co/hhanBG